# Google Earth integrated with Google Maps API v3?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-earth

I'm trying to integrate Google Earth into Google Maps, and I saw it was [possible](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/services.html#Earth) in v2.
But I can't find any doc about how to do so with v3.

Comment: I would also like to know how to do it...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not yet implemented in Google Maps API v3, see the corresponding [ticket](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=1480).

Please note, the more stars a ticket has, the sooner it will be taken care of.

Answer (score 7):

Just a note that there is now an unofficial library at http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/ (trunk at http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/googleearth/)

Comment: You just have to use this javascript (check example folder) http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/source/browse/trunk/googleearth/#googleearth%2Fsrc

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Error: `google[C] is undefined in googleearth-compiled.js`

Comment: Does the demo work for you at http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/googleearth/examples/earth.html ?  It uses that code, and gives me no errors.  If you have troubles what browser and operating system are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Here's my offering: https://github.com/myshen/google-maps-v3-earth-map-type.

It's not from Google but it does do a little more out of the box:

- Links polygons, rectangles, circles, kml, in addition to markers.
- Links mouse events (click, drag, over, out).

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to port [jlivni]'s code to OpenLayers and have setup a GitHub project for that ([1](https://github.com/ZiglioNZ/GoogleEarth-for-OpenLayers)).

Now you can see a demo with Google Maps on one side and Google Earth on the other side:
http://ziglionz.github.com/GoogleEarth-for-OpenLayers/ol.html

Currently the library supports only unstyled placemarks but it shouldn't be too hard to support other features.

The demo also sports a timeline for OpenLayers, that's part of another project ([2](https://github.com/ZiglioNZ/openlayers-timeline)).