# Google earth with Map in api v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Can we get Google earth as a Map Type Id in api v3 ..

As this is done in Google maps also..
[Check it out here](https://maps.google.com/)

Can we do it ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Google ticket requesting to add the "Earth" button to the map type control.

And a more recent (started last summer) issue specifically asking for MapsGL support. (The more stars this issues gets, clicking the start to the left of the issue title...the faster it gets resolved! So add your vote!)

See this question: [Google Earth integrated with Google Maps API v3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3039250/google-earth-integrated-with-google-maps-api-v3?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the `MapTypeId` you can do it like:

```
var mapTypeId = myMap.getMapTypeId();
```

You can set MapType like:

```
myMapObject.setMapTypeId(google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE);
```